# change WhatsApp profile picture through flutter appc

Tags: flutter, whatsapp

i want to change WhatsApp profile picture through my flutter app. can anyone have solution

I want to get WhatsApp profile picture and replace it.

if (Platform.isAndroid) {
try {

```
   final intent = AndroidIntent(
              action: 'ACTION_ATTACH_DATA',
              componentName: 'com.whatsapp.SetAsProfilePhoto',
              category: 'android.intent.category.DEFAULT',
              type: 'image/jpg',
              arguments: {"mimeType": "image/jpg"},
              package: 'com.whatsapp',
            );
```

}